# Django: Choose from related set in db query

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have two models `Product` and `ProductFilter`.

The `ProductFilter` has `priority = IntegerField(...)` field and `active = BooleanField(...)`.

```
class ProductFilter(..):
    products = ManyToManyField('Product....)
```

I want to filter products with the `active = True` field for their `ProductFilter` with the highest priority.

I can choose `product_filter` with the highest priority:

```
product.filters.all().order_by('priority').last()
```

But this needs a for loop which multiplies number of `queries`.

Is it possible to do that in one `Query`? Maybe somehow `aggregate/annotate` the `product_filter` with the highest priority as `active_filter` and then

```
Product.objects.annotate(active_filter=Somehow annotate).filter(active_filter__active=True)
```

Comment: hi, I don't think the product_filter model is necessary regarding the fields you described. could define the fields for the product model itself and make a simple query. higher_pro_products=Product.bojects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-priority')

Comment: So, as I understood, you want to get `products` that have `active=True` in their `product_filter`?